# Ajuda para gravar SESSION usando tag radio

Tags: php

Olá estou usando este código abaixo, para gravar em $_SESSION, mas não estou conseguindo.
Os amigos podem me dar uma ajuda para entender o porque, ou mesmo me mostrar onde estou errando.

```
 <?php 
 @session_start(); // Inicia a session.

 if(!isset($_SESSION['rede_sociais'])){ 
 // Se a Session não existir eu crio...
 $face_status = 'Sim'; // Carrega esse conteúdo

 //Armazena os dados na sessão que pode ser bidimensiona(array)
 $_SESSION['rede_sociais']['face_status']=$face_status;

 }else if(isset($_SESSION['rede_sociais'])){
 // Se existir sessão, eu crio aqui
 $face_status = $_SESSION['rede_sociais']["face_status"];
 }
 ?>

<?php
//pega o valor do botao
$botao=$_POST['face'];
//verifica se o botao foi clicado
if($botao=="Atualizar"){
    $face_status = $_POST["face_status"];
if(!empty($rede_sociais)) {
    $_SESSION['rede_sociais']["face_status"] = $face_status ;

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= cabe_rede_sociais.php'>
<script language='javascript'>
window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
</script>";
}}
?>
        <form method="post">
            <label>Habilitar o Link do FaceBook?</label><br><br>
            <input type='radio' name='face' value='Sim' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
            <input type="radio" name="face" value='Não'><label>Não</label>
            <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">
        </form>
```

Desde já agradeço à todos pela atenção ao meu problema, e no aguardo de boas dicas e ideias para soluciona-lo.

Abraços à todos.

Comment: Eu não vejo em nenhum dos seus `inputs` um com o `name=rede_sociais`. Será por isso?

Comment: Valeu Miguel, por chamar a minha atenção em relação ao input, pois os erros estavam neles. Estou Postando o código funcionando em respondendo a minha própria pergunta, valeu? Grande abraço à todos.

Answer (score 0):

Estou respondendo a minha propria pergunta com o código funcionando.

```
<?php 
@session_start(); // Inicia a session.
if(!isset($_SESSION['rede_sociais'])){ 
// Se a Session não existir eu crio...
$face_status = 'Sim'; // Carrega esse conteúdo

//Armazena os dados na sessão que pode ser bidimensiona(array)
$_SESSION['rede_sociais']['face_status']=$face_status;

}else if(isset($_SESSION['rede_sociais'])){

// Se existir sessão, eu crio aqui
    $face_status = $_SESSION['rede_sociais']["face_status"];
}

<?php
//pega o valor do botao
$botao=$_POST['face'];
//verifica se o botao foi clicado
if($botao=="Atualizar"){
$face_status = $_POST["face_status"];
if(!empty($face_status)) {
$_SESSION['rede_sociais']["face_status"] = $face_status ;

echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; URL= cabe_rede_sociais.php'>
<script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Dados atualizados com sucesso!');
</script>";

}}
?>

<form method="post">
<label>Habilitar o Link do FaceBook?</label><br><br>
<input type='radio' name='face_status' value='Sim' checked="checked"/><label>Sim</label>
<input type="radio" name="face_status" value='Não'><label>Não</label>
<input type="submit" name="face" value="Atualizar">
</form>
```

Espero que ajude a outros amigos com o mesmo problema de gravar na SESSION usando botões (Tag) radio.

Grande abraço à todos.